# How to pass arguments to :simple_one_for_one GenServer to initialize state

Tags: erlang, elixir, gen-server

I am trying to set up a supervision tree for a scheduler application (note using Elixir 1.5 syntax). The application *should* work so that:

- Application boots with a registry & the scheduler supervisor
- The SchedulerSupervisor boots, and allows children to be dynamically added via the `start_child` callback. This takes the initialisation args that are used to build the schedule state.
- The Scheduler, on initialisation, registers its name to the Registry, and initialises with a struct that holds the state (Scheduler then has functions from manipulating schedules, but that isn't relevant to the issue I'm having).

If I *don't* pass any arguments, I can get this working - the Schedules created are not registered, and I have to modify the state after creation. As soon as I try to add arguments, the system errors out - I know it's just a syntax misunderstanding on my part, but I cannot for the life of me figure out what I'm doing wrong. I haven't found the docs terribly helpful here, and I've tried copying and modifying examples from GH, GH Gists and from articles online, but I cannot get it to work.

Current setup - ideally I would want to pass `id`, `period` and `targets` as arguments to `start_child`, but can't even get it working with a single argument, so just sticking with the one until I can get it running:

The Application:

```
defmodule Assay.Application do
  use Application

  def start(_type, _args) do
    children = [
      {Assay.SchedulerSupervisor, []},
      {Registry, keys: :unique, name: Assay.Scheduler.Registry}
    ]

    opts = [strategy: :one_for_all, name: Assay.Supervisor]
    Supervisor.start_link(children, opts)
  end
end
```

The Supervisor:

```
defmodule Assay.SchedulerSupervisor do
    use Supervisor

    @name Assay.SchedulerSupervisor

    def start_link(_args) do
        Supervisor.start_link(__MODULE__, :ok, name: @name)
    end

    def start_schedule(id) do
        Supervisor.start_child(@name, [id])
    end

    def init(_) do
        Supervisor.init([Assay.Scheduler], [strategy: :simple_one_for_one, name: @name])
    end
end
```

The GenServer (only relevant initialisation functions shown)

```
defmodule Assay.Scheduler do
    use GenServer
    alias Assay.Scheduler
    require Logger

    defstruct targets: [], period: 60_000, id: nil, active: false

    def start_link(id) do
        GenServer.start_link(__MODULE__, [id], [name: via_tuple(id)])
    end

    def init([id]) do
        Logger.info "starting a new #{__MODULE__} with id #{id}"
        {:ok, %Scheduler{id: id}}
    end
end
```

edit: actual error might help - I can see that the args are wrong, I just can't figure out why:

```
{:error,
 {:EXIT,
  {:undef,
   [{Assay.Scheduler, :start_link, [[], 1], []},
    {:supervisor, :do_start_child_i, 3, [file: 'supervisor.erl', line: 381]},
    {:supervisor, :handle_call, 3, [file: 'supervisor.erl', line: 406]},
    {:gen_server, :try_handle_call, 4, [file: 'gen_server.erl', line: 636]},
    {:gen_server, :handle_msg, 6, [file: 'gen_server.erl', line: 665]},
    {:proc_lib, :init_p_do_apply, 3, [file: 'proc_lib.erl', line: 247]}]}}}
```

Comment: What's the exact error you're getting?

Comment: ah, sorry, logged error message added @Dogbert

Comment: Are you sure that's the error message for the code in the question? You aren't passing 60000 to start_child but it's there in the error message.

Comment: :\ reload doesn't fully reload stateful things it would seem, edited with now-correct error message

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For `:simple_one_for_one` supervisors, `Supervisor.start_child` calls the start function with the arguments given to it with the arguments specified in the Child Specification. When using `Supervisor.init`, the child specification is taken from the module's `child_spec/1` function in Elixir 1.5. Since you're using `GenServer` and not specifying a custom start function and `[]` is passed to `child_spec/1`, this [defaults to](https://github.com/elixir-lang/elixir/blob/master/lib/elixir/lib/gen_server.ex#L566-L573) `[[]]` which means your function ends up being called with two arguments, `[]` and `1` if the `id` is `1` and you get an undefined function error.

You can fix this by explicitly saying you don't want the GenServer to provide any arguments to the start function in `child_spec` by changing

```
use GenServer
```

to

```
use GenServer, start: {__MODULE__, :start_link, []}
```

Now the function will be called correctly, with only one argument, which will be the `id`.

```
IO.inspect Assay.SchedulerSupervisor.start_link []
IO.inspect Assay.SchedulerSupervisor.start_schedule 12
```

will print:

```
{:ok, #PID<0.82.0>}
[info]  starting a new Elixir.Assay.Scheduler with id 12
{:ok, #PID<0.83.0>}
```

Comment: Fantastic, thank you. I found the docs extremely unclear on this (digging through GitHub issues & seems like there was some discussion on them being unclear when DynamicSupervisor was proposed last year), makes a lot more sense now